# What is this arrow icon that briefly appears in the taskbar notification area?

Tags: windows-11, notification-area

I use Windows 11 and I have been noticing that an arrow icon appears for a few seconds in the task bar notification area then disppears again a few seconds later.

[image: Taskbar arrow]

Does anyone know what this icon is for? When I attempt to click on it to see what it does the arrow just disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This icon is the **Windows Location Services**, it comes up when an app/program/service is using the Location Services.

Same icon in the settings:
[image]

See more details in the [Windows location service and privacy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-location-service-and-privacy-3a8eee0a-5b0b-dc07-eede-2a5ca1c49088#WindowsVersion=Windows_11) info from Microsoft:

> **How we help keep you informed:**
> the location icon When one or more apps
> are currently using your device location through the Windows location
> service, you’ll see the location icon in the notification area of your
> taskbar. Hover over the icon to see the name of the app or apps using
> location.

Comment: Yes! If I open the Windows Maps app the icon appears then when I close the app it disappears again. I guess the random appearances are when a web page requests my location. Thanks :-)

Comment: This icon appears whenever I run a steam game. Strange that they need my location to play an offline game. 